# Trying to get full-size cell images on table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

So I have this going on by using regular image views and buttons to work:

[image]

But now I want it to bounce as the user scrolls, any ideas on how to get this going? I've tried using the table view but I can't figure out how to get the images to be the background. Any perks between using a table view and the current method I'm using? This is a learning experience for me, and that's the whole point of the project. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to achieve what you want *(change image names accordingly)*:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "NewYork")!)
```

For example:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    switch indexPath.row{
    case 0:
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "NewYork")!)
    case 1:
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "LA")!)
    case 2:
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Miami")!)
    default:
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "default")!)
    }
}
```

You can also set it inside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` the same way.

The disadvantage of this is the image either needs to be a repeating pattern or fit the cell size exactly which isn't very flexible for different size devices.

---

Another option is to use a custom table cell and create a UIImageView the same size as the cell.  [Here is a tutorial link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift) describing how to create a custom cell.  Now you can just set the image in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` similar to this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

  switch indexPath.row{
    case 0:
        cell.img_Thumbnail?.image = UIImage(named: "NewYork")
    case 1:
        cell.img_Thumbnail?.image = UIImage(named: "LA")
    case 2:
        cell.img_Thumbnail?.image = UIImage(named: "Miami")
    default:
        cell.img_Thumbnail?.image = UIImage(named: "default")
    }

  return cell
}
```